# How to Create eclipse plugin to use in android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I require to create a plugin for android for reusable components so for any application those features come by default. I found solution for reusable feature is by creating plugin (I dont want to add jar in every project explicitly). Is there any other way? For android, how to add features in plugin classes?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
Vyoma

Comment: Why not to make a library project and include in your project?

Comment: this may help http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html